Obtengo un cero de más al extraer el valor de un campo en un formulario de Windows Forms
Estoy aprendiendo C# y como practica estoy haciendo una app de Windows Forms para llevar registro de mis notas semestrales.
El problema que tengo es que el número decimal que extraigo del NumberUpDown del formulario me aparece con un cero de más cuando ingresa en la base de datos. Ejemplo, sí pongo 4,8 me lo toma como un 48,00.
Ya intenté darle un formato para que me tome el valor exacto con Math.Round(), también usé un TextBox e hice la conversión de string a decimal.
Este es un extracto del código en el que estoy tomando el valor del NumberUpDown para ingresarlo a la BD.
    private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id_materia = Convert.ToInt32(idMateria.SelectedValue);
        string descripcion = txtdesc.Text;
        decimal nota_ = nota.Value;
        decimal porcentaje_ = porcentaje.Value;
        DateTime fecha_ = fecha.Value;

        //insertar
        this.calificacionesTableAdapter1.insertar(id_materia, descripcion,nota_, porcentaje_, fecha_);
        //actualizar tabla
        this.calificacionesTableAdapter1.Fill(this.notasDataSet1.Calificaciones);

    }

La configuración del NumberUpDown

La precisión y la escala en la BD del campo nota es de (5,2). Estoy usando Access.
Quedo atenta a cualquier dato adicional que requieran, gracias de antemano.

El número es con un o con dos decimales? En la configuración tienes 1 decimal, pero termina con 2. Has probado usar punto en vez de coma?

En la configuración lo cambié a 2 para que coincidiera con la escala de la BD y siguió añadiendo ese 0 (arrojaba 480.00 en lugar de 4.80) ahora tengo ambos en 1. También hice el cambio de punto a coma, sigue igual.

Aprender C# con windows forms y access es como aprender latín para saber español.

@Yussef Bastante jodido, me lo están pidiendo para una oferta laboral que realmente necesito conseguir

Decidí cambiar el NumberUpDown por un textbox y pasar de string a decimal, y aunque no es una solución directa a mi problema principal, pude hacer que funcionara provisionalmente. También en la BD de access cambié la precisión y la escala a (5, 1)
decimal nota_ = Convert.ToDecimal(txtN.Text);

Si hay una manera mejor o más eficiente de hacerlo pueden me lo pueden decir. Gracias.

Me alegro de que hayas resuelto tu problema. No obstante, tu respuesta no tiene sentido alguno, nota.Value ya te retornaba un decimal. Tu problema está en la base de datos o como guardas ese dato desde C# a la BD, pero nunca en la Input
